# Bolt cms putting showcases online

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm currently trying to get a showcase to be displayed on bolt, but the textarea and files are not displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the part of the code used for placing content on the page

```
{% block main %}

    {% if app.request.uri == 'http://zernikedecanaat.esy.es/over-ons.html' %}
       {% setcontent page = 'page/1' %}
    {% elseif app.request.uri == 'http://genericsite/1' %}
       {% setcontent page = 'page/2' %}
    {% elseif app.request.uri == 'http://genericsite/2' %}
       {% setcontent page = 'page/3' %}
    {% elseif app.request.uri == 'http://genericsite/3' %}
       {% setcontent page = 'showcase/3' %}
    {% elseif app.request.uri == 'http://genericsite/4' %}
       {% setcontent page = 'showcase/1' %}
    {% elseif app.request.uri == 'http://genericsite/5' %}
       {% setcontent page = 'showcase/2' %} 
    {% endif %}

    <p><h1>{{ page.title }}</h1></p></br>

    <p>{{ page.teaser }}</p></br>

    <p>{{ page.html }}</p></br>

    <p>{{ page.textarea }}</p></br>

    <p>{{ page.file }}</p></br>

    <p>{{ popup(page.image, 1200, 500) }}</p></br>

    <p>{{ page.body }}</p></br>
    {% for file in filelist %}
    {{ page.file }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock main %}
```

It works fine when the contenttype is a page. Titles, teasers, images and the body appears. With showcases only the html area and the title show on the site.

Comment: Update: I replaced the individual fields with             {{ fields(template = 'partials/_sub_fields.twig') }}   which can be found in bolt's base-2016 theme in the map partials. Even though this function is supposed to output every possible type of field, it doesn't put out textarea or files

Comment: Solved the problem. Turns out the site wasn't getting updated due to debug being set to false.

Comment: i find this odly funny becouse i always have the same problem XD